# Add fixed 2 decimals to a number using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to have 2 decimals in a number. 
I tried using :

```
var number = (123).toFixed(2);
```

but it returns it in a string format. I want them to be numbers. 
Also I tried using:

```
var number= parseFloat((123).toFixed(2));
```

but this removes the decimals if it is 0.

I want to show the numbers as decimals with fixed 2 decimals, also convert those numbers to *toLocaleString("bn-IN-u-nu-latn")*
For example:
number = 123456
output : 1,23,456.00

Comment: `1` == `1.00` numerically, so why do you want to show two decimals without using string?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I would understand if you were trying to go from `1.234` to just `1.23`, but giving a whole number decimal places is pointless unless it's to a string.

Comment: Learning basic math rules will explain to you why you can't do that.

Comment: You can't have number 123.00 it's always converted to 123.

Comment: Also I need to show those numbers in a table. so now what happens is in a table the details are displayed, some of the numbers has 2 decimals and some have no decimals at all. It is sometimes confusing to see numbers displayed that way. so adding 2 fixed decimals (00) to non decimals numbers makes it looks better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's impossible. A number won't display trailing zeros past the decimal point. **Only a string will.**

For example, observe this output:

```js
document.write(0.00); // output as a number, is 0
document.write("<br>");
document.write("0.00"); // output as a string, is 0.00
```

If you want a number to be rounded to two decimal places, but also have trailing zeros when needed, you must convert to a string before you output, which means `(123).toFixed(2)` is all you need.

---

**Edit**: To round the number, but also use a locale format. Use [`.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) like such:

```
(0.00).toLocaleString("bn-IN-u-nu-latn", {
    minimumFractionDigits:2,
    maximumFractionDigits:2
});
```

Comment: Yes I did that.
But after converting it to decimals, I have to convert them again to   toLocaleString("bn-IN-u-nu-latn"). Which does not works. So I have to pass it as a Numbers and when I pass it as numbers there is no decimal .00 in those numbers.

Comment: @TagHeuer I updated my answer for how to solve that using the `options` object for `.toLocaleString()`.

Answer (score -1):

Try :
`var number = +parseFloat(Math.round(123 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);`

Comment: *but it returns it in a string format. I want them to be numbers.*

Comment: so for that you can simply add + operator front of parseFloat like, `var number = +parseFloat(Math.round(123 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this ..
Html

```
 Value: <input type="text" id="myText" value="">
```

Javascript

```
<script>
num = 125;
num=num+1;
var R = num.toFixed(2); // returns 126.00
document.getElementById("myText").value = R;
</script>
```

Please see below screen......

[image]

Comment: *but it returns it in a string format. I want them to be numbers.*

Comment: I am not a downvoter but for your clarification just set `var R = num.tofixed(2) + 1` it will display 125.001 which means it concatenate 1 into answere instead of addition

Comment: You can't add numbers like this, if you want to add you have to add before to decimal it will covert automatically. like this num=num+1; OR see above updated answer.